# Check weither particular image name present in the destination folder

Tags: php, html

i am saving the person details along with their profile image which is renamed to their phone number. When i open the person details how can i check that the image with particular name is present in the destination folder.
**example code.**
`$img_src='subscriber_img/'.$response[sub_Phone];
<img src="<?php echo $img_src?>.jpg" class="sub_detail_pic_img" />`

So that if the image source is empty i can add the dummy image to html src="".
Also how to get that images extention as

Comment: You mean [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)? And also for file extension [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: @machineaddict ihave only file name like **my_file** without extension. i've to get the extension of the file from its name. I've no idea about file extension. ONly name

Comment: What do you mean by "i've only name of the file"? If the $response[sub_Phone] is coming from the database, why you didn't stored the extension as well?

Comment: @machineaddict basically this variable is response from server, iam not storing the image name to database.there is no record of file name except the phonenumber which is the name of file with any extension. i have to retrieve the file from the phone number.

Comment: means the name of file is changed to phone number and saved, u've to retrieve through that name with extenstion which might be png,jpg etc..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to detect whether image is present or not for provided input.

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  $img_src = $filename;
} else {
  $img_src = "dummy.jpg";
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo $img_src?>" class="sub_detail_pic_img" />
```

Comment: @v2solutins Half of the job done for file exists but how to check the file extions as i've only name of the file???